# Examples of Completions of Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I'm teaching a class on metric spaces, and I was wondering if anyone had good examples of completions of metric spaces besides $L^p$ spaces (as completion of continuous functions with compact support), Sobolev Spaces (completion of $C^{k,p}$), and p-adic numbers (completion of rationals under p-adic metric)? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!
Intended for students who have just completed a course on real analysis and maybe linear algebra.

Comment: The reals as completion of the rationals?

Comment: Yes though I'm taking this as a given for the course-- at this point they've seen that.

Comment: This is a good motivating example though!!

Comment: not an example (because all my common examples are $L^p,W^{k,p}, C^k$ with suitable norms, and $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ with $X$ normed and $Y$ a Banach space). But here’s an interesting (I think) way of proving existence of completions, other than the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequence argument. Fix a metric space $X$, a point $a\in X$, and let $V$ be the space of Lipschitz functions on $X$ which vanish at the point $a$. The usual Lipschitz seminorm actually becomes a norm (and in fact $V$ is complete, but this is irrelevant). Let $\epsilon:X\to V^*$, $\epsilon(x)=$ the evaluation at $x$ map.

Comment: Then, you can show that $\epsilon$ is an isometric map. Next, we know $V^*$ is always complete (since $\Bbb{R}$ is), so you can define $\overline{\epsilon(X)}$ as the completion of $X$. This was a cool exercise I was given, and I liked it because before that I only knew of the Cauchy equivalence class approach.

Comment: Woah what a great proof! Very similarly, you can map your metric isometrically into the space of bounded continuous functions and then take the closure! That's how I plan to prove it for the class. But this also sounds super cool!

Comment: I'm mostly planning to prove it this way to give the students problems that'll lead up to this, like showing continuous bounded functions under uniform norm are complete, and that closed subsets of complete metric spaces are complete!

Comment: Maybe the Hilbert space direct sum $\{v_i\in\prod_i H_i : \sum_i \|v_i\|_{H_i}^2<\infty\}$ as a the completion of the algebraic direct sum $\{v_i\in\prod_i H_i : v_i=0\ \text{a.e.}\}$ with norm $\sqrt{\sum_i \|v_i\|_{H_i}^2}$?